# d3.json Troubles

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, d3.js, data-visualization

I've spent a good portion of my evening working on this.

I am trying to get this live json data http://citibikenyc.com/stations/json loaded onto a page on my website using d3.json.

Just testing:

```
var bike = "http://citibikenyc.com/stations/json";

d3.json(bike, function(error, json) {
console.log(json);
});
```

doesn't work. I get the error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://citibikenyc.com/stations/json. Origin http://hochemoche.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Is there something that I'm missing? Is there possibly some restriction coming from the page which I'm submitting my request to? Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. I don't believe that there is any restriction coming from citibike's site because this same request works as a curl from my Terminal, also other's have used this data, but can't seem to figure out how they are loading it based on their code.

eg: http://jehiah.cz/citibikenyc

Answer (score 0):

@Blaklaybul

1. The Access-Control-Allow-Origin parameter must be set by the JSON source, in this case it is  "http://citibikenyc.com/stations/json".
2. Try to include the CORS parameters in the header of the ajax request you are making. See http://techblog.constantcontact.com/software-development/using-cors-for-cross-domain-ajax-requests/
3. You can try other alternatives like jsonp etc, again information of which is available in the above link.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've had a friend successfully make the request using php... I'm fairly new to this stuff and hope to get it working!

Can you attempt a get using d3.json to from this site? 
    
    http://citibikenyc.com/stations/json

Comment: Everything seems ok based on http://jsonlint.com/ , but i can't get my code to work

Answer (score 0):

If you use Chrome browser, you might also use an extension namely "**Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: ***". After installing and launching it, I believe it will work.

Hope all thing will be ok!